# How to re-implement `zipmap` in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

As an exercise I am trying to re-implement `zipmap`. The following statement works fine, it takes keys and values and turns them into a map:

```
user=> (into {} (mapv vector [:a :b] [1 2]))
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

However, I run into problem when I try to turn the above statement into a function:

```
user=> ((fn [& xs] (into {} (mapv vector xs))) [:a :b] [1 2])
IllegalArgumentException Vector arg to map conj must be a pair 
Clojure.lang.ATransientMap.conj (ATransientMap.java:37)
```

What is the problem with my implementation and why it happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your sample work by using `apply` to apply `xs` to `mapv vector`.

```
((fn [& xs] (into {} (apply mapv vector xs))) [:a :b] [1 2])
```

This is due to how variadic arguments are bound to `xs`. Without `apply`, you'd essentially be calling it like this `(mapv vector [[:a :b] [1 2]])` but you want it to be called like `(mapv vector [:a :b] [1 2])`.

Comment: `apply` was the missing piece and it looks very idiomatic, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the way you are getting your arguments to your anonymous function

`[& xs]` will **roll the arguments up into a list**

so in your non-function version `(into {} (mapv vector [:a :b] [1 2]))` you're mapping vector over **two collections**

in your function version you're mapping vector over **one collection** and basically doing this:

`(into {} (mapv vector [[:a :b] [1 2]]))` which evaluates to `(into {} [[[:a :b] [1 2]]]])` which gives you an error

**Possible Solutions**:

Since you're trying to re-implement zipmap, why not use the same arg list it uses `[keys vals]` instead of `[& xs]` and write your function like this:

`((fn [keyz valz] (into {} (mapv vector keyz valz))) [:a :b] [1 2])`

You could also unroll the collection yourself:

`((fn [& xs] (into {} (mapv vector (first xs) (second xs)))) [:a :b] [1 2])`

I think using the explicit arg list is a more precise way of going about it since you're expecting to get two specific collections

Comment: Very helpful explanation, thanks! I'm accepting the other answer because it was posted earlier.

Comment: I would use `(second xs)` instead of `(nth xs 1)`.

Comment: Thanks @SeanCorfield I've updated the solution in case someone stumbles upon this and actually uses it, I want them to copy and paste idiomatic code